# Normalize output of keras layer, which make the sum of output 1

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

I want a normalize function like K.l2_normalize, but can make the sum of output 1

L2 normalize formula is:

```
       x
---------------
sqrt(sum(x**2))
```

For example, for an input [3, 1, 4, 3, 1] is [3/6, 1/6, 4/6, 3/6, 1/6]=12/6=1/2

But I want:

```
    x 
---------------
   ||x||
```

For example, for an input [3, 1, 4, 3, 1] is [3/12, 1/12, 4/12, 3/12, 1/12]=12/12=1

In python, I want something like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Lambda

x = tf.keras.layers.Input(tensor=tf.constant([[3, 1, 4, 3, 1]], dtype=tf.float32))
n_layer = Lambda(lambda t: "somefunction" )(x)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(n_layer.eval())
```

---------output--------

```
[[0.25 0.0833 0.3333 0.25 0.0833 ]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is `l1-norm`, so you need to set the order to 1. You can pass the order of the norm through `ord` parameter in [`tf.linalg.norm`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/linalg/normalize?version=stable)

```
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Lambda

x = tf.keras.layers.Input(tensor=tf.constant([[3, 1, 4, 3, 1]], dtype=tf.float32))
n_layer = Lambda(lambda t: tf.linalg.norm(t,ord=1) )(x)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(n_layer.eval())
```

Output:

```
12.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You almost solved my problem.  I simply changed the line by this one: `n_layer = Lambda(lambda t: t/tf.linalg.norm(t,ord=1) )(x)`   And that is right!

Comment: @LiDeyang glad to help!